# Ajax url inside java script in struts 2.0

Tags: struts2

how to use Ajax url inside java script  in struts 2.0.

For example for servlets we write 
url= ControllerServlet?ActionId=myJsp

similarly how to write for struts 2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer.

the url will be -

url= Controller.action?param="value"

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlHttp.open("GET","yourNameSpace/yourActionName?property=value1&property2=value2",true);

xmlHttp.send();
```

Don't get confused by **yourNameSpace** in the above

Check your **namespace** attribute of **package** tag  in struts.xml/struts-config.xml file and give the same there.

If you want to send parameters separately use post ajax request given below.

```
var params = "property1=value1&property2=value2";

xmlhttp.open("POST","yourNameSpace/yourActionName",true);

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

xmlhttp.send(params);
}
```

Hope this helps.